# Cannot get download ID in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working with a chrome extension, in that the download code was like this

```
chrome.downloads.download({
  url: "http://meenkada.net67.net/test.html",
  filename: "test.html" // Optional
});
```

But with this I did not get the download ID. So, I modified the code as below

```
function DownloadCallback()
{
alert('hi');

}

chrome.downloads.download({
 url: "http://meenkada.net67.net/test.html",
  filename: "test.html" // Optional
},function DownloadCallback);
```

but I am not able to get the download ID. Its for opening the downloaded file. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a javascript syntax error.

I recommend working with Chrome dev tools open so that you can catch those faster.

The syntax is

```
// Anonymous function
chrome.downloads.download({url: ..., filename: ...}, function(downloadId) {
    console.log(downloadId);
});
```

or

```
// Common function
function myHandler(filenameId) {
    console.log(filenameId);
}

chrome.downloads.download({url: ..., filename: ...}, myHandler);
```

or

```
// Anonymous function stored in variable
var myHandler = function(filenameId) {
    console.log(filenameId);
}

chrome.downloads.download({url: ..., filename: ...}, myHandler);
```

Comment: Yes, this is working well. But when I give it to open the file and acceptDanger function both are not working. For open file its giving as user gesture required and for accept danger its not accepting the file

Comment: Hello. open another question for that if you can't manage to solve it :)